# Caching unique emails in redis

Tags: php, caching, redis

So I'm adding Redis to an existing project and I want to cache every user in the system like this:

```
'sample@sample.com' => '101'
```

Where 101 is the users primary key field.
I need this functionality so that when a user is registering on the website we can very quickly check the cache to see if this email address already belongs to another user.
We can also use this when a user is changing the email address on their account, and even at login, when the user provides their login details we can just check the cache to see if they have provided a unique email address, and then the value (in this case 101) will point us to their row in the users table (also cached).

I'm just wondering what's the best way to store this in redis. Should I just use some key like this:

```
set sample@sample.com 101
```

or would it make more sense to use a hash map like this:

```
hset sample@sample.com id 101
```

Or is there some other way of doing it?
I basically just need a very efficient way of querying the email address and either getting the users ID back (if it already exists) or null (if the email address is not in the system already).

Answer (score 0):

As you say you want to use the Redis as a cache so the the email->ID are not expected to live there forever?
In case of temporary cache you should use SETEX - version of SET with expiration (10 seconds in example below).

```
setex sample@exanple.com 10 101
```

And don't forget to refresh the expiration when needed (10 seconds in example below):

```
expire sample@exanple.com 10
```

Using HSET instead of SET makes sense only if you want to keep in cache more complicated data than plain integer or string ID.